# The four-legged spider experiment

Tags: spring, neural-network, weka, robotics, pi4j

let me start saying that I'm new to neural networks, Machine Learning etc, and so far I have just made few very simple experiments to learn so please be patient with me also If I ask very naive or long questions. 
My favorite coding language is java and I'm looking at playing with Weka. To play with this API that looks like to me
being very clear and complete, this time, to have something more than a set of ideal data to train and check the success rate, I started not from just the software but from a real world problem that I created for myself.
The problem I created and that I'd like to solve with neural networks, is a four legged spider shaped robot controlled by a Raspberry PI with some ADC and servo Hats. This sort of strange robot has 4 legs, each leg being made 
of 3 parts, each part is moved by a servo motor. In total I have so 4 legs * 3 leg parts = 12 servo motors. On each servo motor I have a 3 axis analog accellerometer attached (12 in total) I can read from the Raspberry PI. 
From each of these accellerometers I read 2 axis to determine the position of each servo, that is the position of each leg segment for each leg. In addition, the "sole of the foot" of each of the 4 legs, has a button to 
determine if the leg has reached the floor and is sustaining the spider. The spider construction blog is here, for those interested: https://thestrangespider.blogspot.com/
The purpose of this experiment is to make the spider able to put itself in balance and set itself horizontally starting from any condition. 
The spider should be able in few words, to level horizontally its body regardless of the fact that I have put the spider on a horizontal or oblique surface. The hardware platform is ready, I miss few details but let's assume 
I can read all the signals I need  from a java Spring boot application using the PI4J APIs to interface hardware (24 values from ADC for 12 servos and 4 digital inputs (true/false) from the buttons on 
the soles of the spider feets). The intent it to solve the problem of moving the legs servo motors using neural networks built with Weka, reading the various input signals until the system reaches the 
success condition (static balance and body in a horizontal position). The main problem is how to use all the data I have to build a data set in the best way, what neural networks to use to put in place
 the adaptive corrective feedback, until the spider reaches the success condition of having its body finally horizontal and in static balance.

Going deeper into this topic, let me provide my analysis.

Each leg should perform this steps:

Can move independently one servo per time starting from a random position (in the range of the angle allowed by the leg portion)

Re-read after each move, all the legs segments position, waiting for the next static condition

Determine if last move has brought an advantage or a disadvantage to the system as a whole.

If no change happened because of the last move, keep the latest change/move and continue

If any max angle has been reached, change the direction for that angle next move

Check if system success is closer now respect to previous step and determine next action type

The problem to me is a mix of open questions where one is how to represent this system from a data perspective:

Data coming from acceletometers all belonging from servos in the same legs are candidates for a cluster of data or a robot sub-system ?

Can each servo and its position measurement be a subsystem of the main system instead ?

Can these be multiple problems instead of one really ?

How would you approach this problem from a neural network perspective ?

Comment: Please try to improve the readability of your post. It will make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

after studying Weka classification and regression, I finally got to the conclusion that the processing should be a regression problem. That ended as well in a too complex problem that would have need regression with multi label output that apart from Weka would have required another framework on top of that called Meka.

Finally I got to a conclusion that now I will try that is, using first Weka to classify data and detect first on which length the inclination is, the solve the single specific problem of acting on that leg eventually with a different Weka model working only on a single leg per time.

Problem resolution so, will have these steps:

Use a legs Weka classification model first to detect which of the four legs has the higher inclination.

Use a leg specific Weka classification to correct for the leg detected above in first step, the actions to be taken by the three leg segments in order to correct the problem.

Stefano

Comment: Anwering my own question: after spending lot of time both on robotics and electronics, finally it seems to work: https://thestrangespider.blogspot.com/2021/06/ann-leg-tilting-classification-finally.html?m=1